# List all user directories and look for specific file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm working on a script which will check for a specific file in ~/ of all users with home directory.

I tried `ls /home` and cd into users into their home directories but it gives too many arguments error.

```sh
username=$(ls /home)
cd /home/$username
cat file.json
```

I except the output of json file but it doesn't gives output of json file even user have a json file.

## Edit:

Now I need to extract username of users with file `file.json` I have tried to do this with `grep` but it didn't worked.

```sh
files=$(find /home -name tilde.json -print)
echo "$files" >> jsons.txt
cat jsons.txt | grep /*/
```

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `getent passwd | cut -d : -f 6`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will find and list all files called `file.json` under the `/home` directory:

```
find /home -name file.json -print
```

You may want to redirect errors to `/dev/null` in the event you don't have access to all users' home dirs.

If you want to print out the contents of all these files, try:

```
find /home -name file.json -print -exec cat {} \;
```

To limit the search to only the directories under `/home` (i.e. not `/home` itself, and no sub directories in the user home), use:

```
find /home -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name file.json -print -exec cat {} \;
```

I also added the `-type` flag there to limit the search to files and exclude any dirs that may happen to share the name.

Answer (score 0):

This'll do:

```
cat /home/*/file.json
```

It'll print

> cat: '/home/*/file.json': No such file or directory

on standard error if it can't find any.

Comment: How can I get to start again if file empty?

Comment: At this point you probably want to update the question to clarify what you are actually trying to do. I'm not going to build a program by getting feature requests one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
cd /home
find . -name file.json -maxdepth 1 -exec cat {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `/home` contains `user1` and `user2`.

Then your `cd` command is invoked as

```
cd /home/user1 user2
```

That's not what you wanted, and isn't valid syntax for `cd`, which accepts only a single argument.  You probably wanted a `for` loop instead.

If you can't predict such expansions, `set -x` enables tracing, which may provide insight into what commands are actually run, and would show your problem here.  `set +x` to turn it off again.

Finally, note that not all users' home directories are necessarily in home.  You might want to use `getent` or similar to find all user home directories.